# pandas: Join function resulting in NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes I need to join;

df1 looks like this--

```
    Year             President            Party   
0   1920         Woodrow Wilson      Democratic     
1   1921      Warren G. Harding      Republican     
2   1922      Warren G. Harding      Republican
```

df2 looks like this (Dow Jones Returns)

```
               Value
Date                
1920-12-31       NaN         
1921-12-31  0.127172         
1922-12-31  0.217386
```

I am trying to join df1 with df2: table = df1.join(df2)

but when I do that, the Value column in table is reduced to all NaNs. 
Can someone please guide me on this. Thank you...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`map` + `assign`**

- build a dictionary to `map` with where the `year` of `df2`s index are the keys and the `df2's`Value` are the values.
- use `map` with `df1`s `Year` column.
- `assign` this to a new column `Value` attached to `df1`

---

```
df1.assign(Value=df1.Year.map(dict(zip(df2.index.year, df2.Value))))

   Year          President       Party     Value
0  1920     Woodrow Wilson  Democratic       NaN
1  1921  Warren G. Harding  Republican  0.127172
2  1922  Warren G. Harding  Republican  0.217386
```

---

**`join`**

Otherwise, you can stick with `join` like this

```
df1.join(df2.set_index(df2.index.year), on='Year')

   Year          President       Party     Value
0  1920     Woodrow Wilson  Democratic       NaN
1  1921  Warren G. Harding  Republican  0.127172
2  1922  Warren G. Harding  Republican  0.217386
```